# making a C program that measures the size of cache block

Tags: c, caching

The program declares the large array, using the `sbrk(`) function. Sbrk changes the data segment size by the specified increment.  standard library functions I am using, eg.:

```
#include  <stdio.h>  
#include <sys/time.h>  
#include <unistd.h>
```

my main() function starts out by declaring a variable: 
    register *a;
my goal is to try to put all the variables I will use during the memory accesses into registers since the only 
memory accesses I want are to the array. If local variables would reside in memory, accessing them 
could have an effect on the measurements. 
Next thing is to allocate the array, an array of around 4 million integers, that is 16 MB on 32-bit 
machines.

```
a=sbrk(4*1024*4096+8192);
a=(int  *)((((int)a>>13)<<13)+8192);
```

When a program is started, some memory is allocated to it. The function `sbrk()` increases this memory 
by the given amount. After the function call, "a" will point to the beginning of this huge array.

Now I have these peice I dont know what to do inorder to get the size of the cacheblock, any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with all this?

Comment: im trying to find the size of cacheblock

Comment: What is it exactly that you want? Do you want to know the cache sizes of your processor? Is it a x86 based processor? You do know there is normally more then one cache.

Comment: yea measure the size of the processor's cache and cache block

Comment: On Linux specifically you might parse `/proc/cpuinfo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way with straight C that I'm aware of to get cache line sizes.  If you are on an x86 processor you can query the CPU using cpuid for the cache line size.

[This page](http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/simd/cpuid.php) contains an explanation of how to do so.  Scroll down to `CPUID — Detecting Cache Line Sizes`.

> Finding a processor's Cache Line Size is helpful if you want to
>   aggressively flush and prefetch data into the cache using instructions
>   like prefetch and clflush. Detecting this is different depending on
>   who makes the CPU.
>
> For Intel Microprocessors, the Cache Line Size can be calculated by
>   multiplying bh by 8 after calling cpuid function 0x1.
>
> For AMD Microprocessors, the data Cache Line Size is in cl and the
>   instruction Cache Line Size is in dl after calling cpuid function
>   0x80000005.
>
> Knowing the Cache Line Size allows you to dispatch effective
>   prefetches and flushes, and can also help you align data to Cache Line
>   boundaries to avoid loading from split Cache Lines, which can affect
>   performance.